# How do I enable cache in iPad

Tags: ipad, ios, web-app

I want to be able to use an HTML5 WebApp, but my iPad won't cache the manifest. The WebApp works on Android and BlackBerry devices, so I know it's not the code.

And is it different for the various iPad versions?

I have the first gen. iPad, but I will need to be able to help folks with more recent iPads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Settings > Safari > Accept cookies > Always
```

Comment: Haven't tried the above solution yet, but I bet it was the root cause of my client's issues. @SnowboardingBruin: do you know what this setting is set to by default on iPad 1? (quite old iOS, I think 5.0 - 5.1)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to enable; all versions of iOS Safari on all iOS devices [support the cache manifest](http://caniuse.com/#feat=offline-apps) by default and I'm not aware of any way to turn it off.

Issues you're seeing are probably caused by bugs or unexpected behavior in iOS, Safari, or your code.